# I Run my flutter project in android studio and try to use an IPhone 12 simulator but the Xcode builld fails everytime

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, appdelegate, podfile

I am working on a Macbook Pro 2019. I want to use Firebase/Auth, Firebase/Firestore, Firebase/Analytics and Firebase/Core. I think there is something wrong with the podfile.
Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'


# Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
#pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

# For Analytics without IDFA collection capability, use this pod instead
# pod ‘Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport’

# Add the pods for any other Firebase products you want to use in your app
# For example, to use Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
#pod 'Firebase/Auth'
#pod 'Firebase/Firestore'



# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'


  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
   config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
  end
 end
end
```

Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
      [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
  }
}
```

Error:

Running "flutter pub get" in ProjectZeus...
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           10.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Check that, you have added the google-services properly, using Xcode